# How to resolve "One or more errors occurred" issue when using google calendar api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

i am using google calendar api service to access user calendar, and it is working fine for me in my local, but it is not working in server below is the code which is working fine in my local.

```
public ActionResult AddGoogleEvent()
{          
    UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = clientid,
           ClientSecret = clientsecret,
        },
        new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None).Result;

    var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer(){
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "sampleappilication"
        });

    Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event event1 = new Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event()
    {
        Summary = "Appointment",
        Location = location,
        Start = new Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventDateTime()
        {
            DateTime = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(yy), Convert.ToInt32(mn), Convert.ToInt32(dy), Convert.ToInt32(sthour), Convert.ToInt32(stminute), 0),
            TimeZone = location
        },
        End = new Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventDateTime()
        {
            DateTime = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(yy), Convert.ToInt32(mn), Convert.ToInt32(dy), Convert.ToInt32(ethour), Convert.ToInt32(etminute), 0),
            TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        Recurrence = new String[] {"RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO"},
        Attendees = new List<Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventAttendee>()
        {
            new Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventAttendee() { Email = attendencess }
        }
    };

    Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event thisevent = service.Events.Insert(event1, "primary").Execute(); // Another error. "Does not contain a definition for Fetch"

    string newEventID = thisevent.Id;

    Session["Accepted"] = "Accepted";
    return RedirectToAction("Eventconfirm");
}
```

Exception

> Access to the path 'Google.Apis.Auth' is denied. StackTrace:at
>   Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSu‌​ccess(Tasktask)atMic‌​rosoft.Runtime.Compi‌​lerServices.TaskAwai‌​ter.HandleNonSuccess‌​(Task
>   task)at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNe‌​xt()
>   in
>   C:\Users\mdril\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src‌​\GoogleApis.Auth.Dot‌​Net4\OAuth2\GoogleWe‌​bAuthorizationBroker‌​.cs:line
>   59 Source: Microsoft.Threading.Tasks TargetSite: Void
>   ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)

Can any one suggest how to fix this

Comment: "Not working" is pretty vague - what exactly is going wrong, and where? (I'm hoping you have an exception stack trace somewhere...)

Comment: yes while checking in log file i am getting the following exception.

One or more errors occurred.
StackTrace:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at O365_APIs_Start_ASPNET_MVC.Controllers.ICalendarController.<AddGoogleEvent>d__104.MoveNext() in D:\O365Calender_App_New\O365Calender_App\O365-APIs-Start-ASPNET-MVC\Controllers\ICalendarController.cs:line 4678
Source: mscorlib
TargetSite: TResult GetResultCore(Boolean)
-----------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Firstly, that should be in the question, not in a comment - and next, you should find the *real* original exception in `InnerExceptions`. Without that information, it's going to be incredibly hard to help you.

Comment: Thanks Jon for your support

But when running in my local i am not getting any exceptions, i am getting issue when running in server only

Comment: Hi Jon, Getting inner exception as follows
Message: Access to the path 'Google.Apis.Auth' is denied.
StackTrace:at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Tasktask)atMicrosoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.<AuthorizeAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\mdril\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs:line 59
Source: Microsoft.Threading.Tasks
TargetSite: Void ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)

Comment: Right, and now that you've given those details, the answer is reasonably clear...

Answer (score 1):

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = clientid,
            ClientSecret = clientsecret,
        },
        new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

By default that code uses FileDataStore to store your credentials.  FileDataStore will by default store the credentials in %appData%.  My tutorial on filedatastore can be found [here](http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/)

> Access to the path 'Google.Apis.Auth' is denied

Probably means that your server doesn't have access to write to that path.  You can do something like this to change the path that the credentials are stored.

```
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(clientSecretsJsonFilePath
                               ,FileMode.Open
                               ,FileAccess.Read))
  {   
  credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
  GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
  new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
  "LookIAmAUniqueUser",
   CancellationToken.None,
  new FileDataStore(@"c:\datastore",true)                              
  ).Result;
  }
```

Alternatively you can also create your own implementation of [idatastore](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/d78d382ea7bdf2ea553e444d13611c66594098f4/Src/GoogleApis.Core/Apis/Util/Store/IDataStore.cs) and store the credentials how ever you like

Comment: Hi Dalm,
i am getting issue with DriveService.Scope.Drive in which namespace i get that

Comment: You don't need it you are using google calendar I just copied code figured you could fix it.  I have done so for you.

Comment: Hi Dalm, how can i add my client secrets in json file, can you please explain that it will help me to fix the issue

Comment: https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/Genreated-samples1.0/Calendar%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.cs

Comment: Thanks Dalm, i have downloaded json file with client secrets in google console and finally i fixed the issue Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync works in a console app (or locally in the dev machine) but for a web app you need a web flow.

Please check this links:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implementing-oauth2-0-authorization-for-google-in-asp-net/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46604699/6080079

the first one is to get an accessToken and the second one is to get a service from that token.

Hope this help!